# DIY HiFi System components

Tags: audio, components, stereo

I'd like to create small HiFi home system with few requirements:

1. It should use ONLY HDD of up to 100 GB  (No CDs, Radio or other crap!)
2. With remote control
3. With small screen/monitor for easy visual navigation
4. With good quality speakers only stereo output (WAV, FLAC or 320kbps MP3)
5. Nothing complicated in the menu - Play/Stop/Back/Forward. Navigate in folder hierarchy(i.e. Up/Down/Enter or Open).
6. Preferable language C# but could go with C++ or C;
7. No android or any other OS as as platform just a simple audio player.

I've been trying to find development board for a few days but (being a software developer and not knowing component's markings and functions) I can't figure out what parts and components do I actually need. I wouldn't want to physically build the system (like soldering etc.) just a development board, that would have all (or most of) required components built in, and that would need only programming.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats wrong wtih something like an atom running linux?

Comment: I don't want it to complicated.. You know - first you have to start OS then find/start Audio playback application etc. etc.. Instead I'd like something that would show folder structure straight away after start button was pressed.

Comment: And apart from that I'm not a great expert in Linux....

Comment: And writing the drivers for all your peripherals is less complicated?

Comment: Yeah but that would be different :))) Ok I'll be honest -  I don't want any OS underneath it...

Comment: So you feel capable of writing your own device drivers, but can't find any hardware to do it on? hm...

Comment: Honestly, by the end of this effort, you would have something that probably resembled an incredibly custom OS.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's for home use but.. also I have some plans for that ... if it will work of course... )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pic32 audio development board would support everything that you want. A screen with buttons. Stereo output for audio. USB host support that should be able connect either a thumb driver or external hard drive. The only things it requires is software. Microchip's XC32 supports both C and C++. It would be a tall order to write all of this software because it would all have to be written from nearly scratch.

http://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=DM320011

Comment: Is it this one..? http://www.em.avnet.com/en-us/design/drc/Pages/MicrochipPIC32AudioDevBoard.aspx   I just can't get it - it says ...for PIC32

Comment: Are there few modules..?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the link. http://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=DM320011

Comment: Now that looks promising! Thanks a bunch vini_i!!!